# Random Linux Command invokes Vim and it fails with "Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal"

Tags: vim

I am getting this error when executing random commands in my linux machine:

```
# man ls
Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
Vim: Error reading input, exiting...
Vim: preserving files...
Vim: Finished.
```

```
man: command exited with status 1: LESS=-ix8RmPm Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$PM Manual page ls(1) ?ltline %lt?L/%L.:byte %bB?s/%s..?e (END):?pB %pB\%.. (press h for help or q to quit)$-R MAN_PN=ls(1) vim -R +AnsiEsc
```

This happens for a lot of commands. How can I fix this?

```
# echo $PAGER
vim -R +AnsiEsc
```

I am using `/bin/zsh` and recently had updated it.

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
```

Comment: It looks like the output is redirecting to  vim. What shell are you using? Could you provide more info such as aliases set, your .bashrc incase you are using bash.

Comment: What is the value of your `PAGER` environment variable?

Comment: `vim -R +AnsiEsc` is my `PAGER` Env value

Comment: @larsks I removed the `export PAGER=vim -R +AnsiEsc` and things are normal now. Thank you. What had been going wrong? Please feel free to answer your rationale and that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: You obviously had some misconfiguration in your `PAGER` setting, since `man` wouldn't otherwise be launching `vim`. While it is possible to use `vim` as a pager, I haven't tried it so I can't comment on whether or not your settings were correct.